# How to attach Attachment to SalesForce Case?

Tags: c#, salesforce

I am creating a case in salesfore from code. I'm not sure how to add the attachment to it.

I assume this needs to be done in 2 calls.

1) Create the case

2) Attach when we have the CaseId.

Here is what I have so far

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
attachment.Body = salesForceCaseData.Attachment;
attachment.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
attachment.Name = "Support Console Screenshot";
```

I'm not sure how to tie this in next. Does below need to be the CaseId?

```
attachment.ParentId
```

Also once that is done i'm guessing I just need to use

```
SaveResult[] results = sf.create(sObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to set the parentId of the attachment to the Id of the case you just created. And yes, you use create to create the attachment, just like the case.